# MVVMCROSS Android ListView Refresh

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have created a listview.axaml and inside that listview i am calling my custom template.axml file.

Below is how my listview look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyLists; ItemClick ShowDetailCommand"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/customlistview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

below is how my custom template look likes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/greenColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Status" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOfList"
            android:layout_weight="0.8">
            <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_color"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:singleLine="true"
                local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/rightArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my Adapter class where i am changing the image based on certain value

public class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
    {
        Activity _activity;
        private int _position;

```
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
        : base(context, bindingContext)
    {
        _activity = (Activity)context;
    }       

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {         
        return base.GetView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, int templateId)
    {
        var view = convertView ?? _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomListView, null, false);

        if (source is Project.Mobile.Core.Models.MyList)
        {
            ImageView imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Status);

            switch ((int)source.Flag)
            {
                case 1:

                    imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.greenColor);
                    break;
                case 2:

                    imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.yellowColor);
                    break;
                case 3:

                    imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.redColor);
                    break;
                default:

                    imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.greenColor);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return base.GetBindableView(view, source, templateId);
    }
}
```

I am changing the imageview using the CustomAdapter class...

I am able to change the ImageView image using the GetBindableView method but on the ui it is not refreshing immediately but when we scroll the listview then the image get reflected.

can any one help me in this to get sorted.

Ui doesn't get refreshed immediately?

Thanks,
Aaman

**Edited**

Please find the ValueConverterCode below

```
    public class ImageChangeValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<int, string>
    {
        protected override string Convert(int value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string strImage = string.Empty;
            switch ((int)value)
            {
                case 1:
                    strImage = "res:greenColor";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    strImage = "res:yellowColor";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    strImage = "res:redColor";
                    break;
                default:
                    strImage = "res:greenColor";
                    break;
            }
            return strImage ;
        }
     }
```

Note:- My Image are lying inside Resources/Drawable folder

Comment: Why are you not using a converter for that image? You are missing the whole point of using Mvvm if you are using a custom adapter for this kind of thing...

Comment: Yes, you are right using converter will be the ideal choice but i have tried that first than move on to using Adapter, kIndly find my code for converter

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue using converter but on the ui level i have used DrawableName instead of ImageUrl like below

```
       <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/taskStatus"
        local:MvxBind="DrawableName DynamicImageChange" />
```

And converter class returns string like below

```
protected override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string ImagePath = string.Empty;
            ImagePath = "@drawable/greenstriponlist";
            return ImagePath ;
        }
```

I hope this might help someone.

Note:- Using mvvmcross 3.1 version